# AngularJS ngclass, remove class if state exists

Tags: angularjs

I have the following body tag

```
<body class="loaderParent" ng-class="">
```

how do I remove the loaderParent class if $state.includes('home') ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<body ngClass="{loaderParent: !$state.includes('home')}">
```

Why don't you read [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)?

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, I did not see state handling in there.

Comment: That has nothing to do with state handling. ngClass takes an object with class names as keys and booleans as values. If the boolean value is true, the correcponding class name is added. Otherwise, it's removed. The boolean condition can be any expression evaluated on the scope, as all the other angular expressions. Whether this expression is based on state or anything else is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the help JB Nizet, I have a lot of reading ahead of me.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an object in `ng-class` like so:

```
<body ng-class="{ loaderParent: callControllerMethod() }">
```